# fitting beta normal distribution to data

Tags: r, distribution, probability, normal-distribution

I want to fit betanormal distribution to my data

```
X=c(5.20 , 6.80, 11.00, 21.00 ,25.50, 28.50, 30.90 ,30.90, 27.20, 17.70 ,10.50 , 6.70, 5.00,  8.00 ,14.30, 20.90 ,24.10 ,28.40 ,29.80, 30.80 ,26.80 ,20.50, 12.50 , 9.30, 19.20 , 5.60,  9.20  ,1.80 ,15.80 ,22.20 ,27.90, 30.60 ,31.10 ,28.80 ,23.30, 13.40, 4.30 , 6.80  ,7.20 ,10.30 ,17.00, 21.20 ,27.40 ,32.10, 30.20 ,25.50, 22.20, 11.30, 6.00  ,6.60 , 9.80 ,14.20 ,16.10 ,22.00 ,29.30 ,29.30 ,31.30, 26.20, 20.30 ,13.30, 5.30  ,5.00,  4.80 ,13.00 ,18.90 ,22.40, 28.30, 32.40 ,30.20 ,27.20 ,21.30, 12.00, 10.20  ,3.00 , 9.80 ,14.10 ,19.30, 24.80, 30.30 ,31.40 ,31.60, 26.40, 31.60, 11.50, 4.00 , 4.70  ,7.60, 10.00 ,17.20 ,24.20, 29.10 ,30.90 ,30.40 ,26.50, 20.00, 14.60, 5.80, -2.00 , 5.00 ,17.00, 20.70 ,23.90, 28.80 ,31.60 ,30.20 ,27.30 ,20.70 ,11.70, 7.40 , 5.40  ,9.10 ,13.80 ,14.20 ,23.70 ,26.80 ,31.70 ,29.80 ,24.40 ,19.40, 11.90, 7.40 , 8.90 , 8.90 ,14.50 ,18.01 ,23.20 ,30.00 ,32.00 ,29.10 ,25.80 ,23.30 ,13.00, 9.80)
```

and im using fitdistplus distribution but it doesnt have this distribution and want to define its density and distriburion.i define density as follows

```
mu=mean(data)
sigma=sd(data)
Phi=pnorm((x-mu)/sigma)
phi=dnorm((x-mu)/sigma)
dbetanorm=function(a,b){
((gamma(a+b))/(sigma*gamma(a)*gamma(b)))*phi*(Phi)^(a-1)((1-Phi)^(b-1))
}
```

but i cannot define pbetanorm.the formula of it is

```
F(x)=I_Φ((x-μ)/σ)  (a,b)
```

does anyone know how to do this in R?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to get this is using `pbetanorm(...)` in the `VGAM` package. Documentation [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/VGAM.pdf).

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(VGAM)

set.seed(1)       # for reproducible example
X <- rbetanorm(1000,2,6)
params <- fitdist(X,distr=dbetanorm,start=list(shape1=1,shape2=1),
                  fix.arg=list(mean=0,sd=1))
params
# Fitting of the distribution ' betanorm ' by maximum likelihood 
# Parameters:
#        estimate Std. Error
# shape1 2.010134 0.08380233
# shape2 5.980691 0.27065835

# always plot the results...
hist(X,freq=F,xlim=c(-3,1),ylim=c(0,1),breaks=20)
x <- seq(-3,1,.1)
lines(x,dbetanorm(x,params$estimate[1],params$estimate[2]),col="red",lty=2)
```

[image]

**EDIT** Response to OP's inclusion of data.

This is a great object lesson in the *importance of including your data in the question!!!*

So there are several things going on here. First and most important, the fit might be poor because your data is not betanormal distributed. why do you believe it is?

Second, the betanormal distribution has 4 parameters, `shape1`, `shape2`, `mean`, and `sd`. In my example I fixed the latter two to show how it's done, and because you seem to assume values in your question. In the real case, it may be important to fit all 4 parameters.

Third, `fitdistr(...)` uses the `optim(...)` function to do the actual fitting. `optim(...)` uses local minimization, which means that if your initial parameter estimates are not reasonably close to the true values, you might get a "fit" (local minimum) which is a poor representation to your data. After experimenting a bit it became clear that for your dataset, shape1 << 1 and shape2 < 1. So re-fitting with better initial estimates:

```
params <- fitdist(X,distr=dbetanorm,
                  start=list(shape1=.001,shape2=.01,mean=mean(X),sd=1))
params
# Fitting of the distribution ' betanorm ' by maximum likelihood 
# Parameters:
#           estimate  Std. Error
# shape1  0.01898767 0.010817437
# shape2  0.01562771 0.009071755
# mean   17.36844300 0.870978734
# sd      0.89752769 0.265374668


hist(X,freq=F,xlim=c(-5,35),ylim=c(0,.08),breaks=20)
x <- seq(min(X),max(X),.1)
with(params,lines(x,dbetanorm(x,estimate[1],estimate[2],estimate[3],estimate[4]),
                  col="red",lty=2))
```

gives this:

[image]

which is still not great.

Without a lot more work, I'm inclined to say that your data is just not betanormal distributed. Might it be the sum of two distributions?